# NDSolve error message: Cannot find starting value for the variable y'

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm attempting to solve a differential equation using NDSolve. This is the code:

```
NDSolve[{y'''[x] + 0.5*y[x]*y''[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y'[Infinity] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

but I got the following error

> NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable y'

I need a solution that satisfies that initial conditions but if I change those conditions I keep getting the same error. So I don't know if the problem is with the initial conditions or with the implementation itself.

For the record: I'm using Mathematica 9.0.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/how-to-solve-ode-with-boundary-at-infinity

Comment: Definitely it was that infinite. Thank you so much!