# Oscillations on solution of finite difference equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

In a [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160942/12558) on the solution of an ODE with a boundary conditon at infinty I had some excelent help from xzczd and am now returning with a further problem along the same lines. I have used the code pdetoae which may be found in [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/12558).

The problem is that the solution has oscillations. These oscillations are particularly clear on the first and second derivatives of the solution which I need.

The ODE, initial and final conditions and the variables are:

```
    inf = 15;
nn = 2; eqns = {(-α + 
      2*α*Derivative[1][a[0]][y]^2 + α*
       Derivative[1][a[1]][y]^2 + α*
       Derivative[1][a[2]][y]^2 + α*
       Derivative[1][b[1]][y]^2 + α*Derivative[1][b[2]][y]^2 - 
      2*α*a[0][y]*Derivative[2][a[0]][y] - α*a[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[1]][y] - α*a[2][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[2]][y] - α*b[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[1]][y] - α*b[2][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[2]][y] - 2*Derivative[3][a[0]][y])/2 == 
   0, (4*α*Derivative[1][a[0]][y]*Derivative[1][a[1]][y] + 
      2*α*Derivative[1][a[1]][y]*Derivative[1][a[2]][y] + 
      2*Derivative[1][b[1]][y] + 
      2*α*Derivative[1][b[1]][y]*Derivative[1][b[2]][y] - 
      2*α*a[1][y]*Derivative[2][a[0]][y] - 
      2*α*a[0][y]*Derivative[2][a[1]][y] - α*a[2][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[1]][y] - α*a[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[2]][y] - α*b[2][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[1]][y] - α*b[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[2]][y] - 2*Derivative[3][a[1]][y])/2 == 
   0, (2 - 2*Derivative[1][a[1]][y] + 
      4*α*Derivative[1][a[0]][y]*Derivative[1][b[1]][y] - 
      2*α*Derivative[1][a[2]][y]*Derivative[1][b[1]][y] + 
      2*α*Derivative[1][a[1]][y]*Derivative[1][b[2]][y] - 
      2*α*b[1][y]*Derivative[2][a[0]][y] - α*b[2][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[1]][y] + α*b[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[2]][y] - 
      2*α*a[0][y]*Derivative[2][b[1]][y] + α*a[2][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[1]][y] - α*a[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[2]][y] - 2*Derivative[3][b[1]][y])/2 == 
   0, (-α + α*Derivative[1][a[1]][y]^2 + 
      4*α*Derivative[1][a[0]][y]*
       Derivative[1][a[2]][y] - α*Derivative[1][b[1]][y]^2 + 
      4*Derivative[1][b[2]][y] - 
      2*α*a[2][y]*Derivative[2][a[0]][y] - α*a[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[1]][y] - 
      2*α*a[0][y]*Derivative[2][a[2]][y] + α*b[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[1]][y] - 2*Derivative[3][a[2]][y])/2 == 
   0, (-4*Derivative[1][a[2]][y] + 
      2*α*Derivative[1][a[1]][y]*Derivative[1][b[1]][y] + 
      4*α*Derivative[1][a[0]][y]*Derivative[1][b[2]][y] - 
      2*α*b[2][y]*Derivative[2][a[0]][y] - α*b[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][a[1]][y] - α*a[1][y]*
       Derivative[2][b[1]][y] - 
      2*α*a[0][y]*Derivative[2][b[2]][y] - 
      2*Derivative[3][b[2]][y])/2 == 0};
ic0 = {a[0][0] == 0, Derivative[1][a[0]][0] == 0, a[1][0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][a[1]][0] == 0, b[1][0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][b[1]][0] == 0, a[2][0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][a[2]][0] == 0, b[2][0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][b[2]][0] == 0};
bc = {Derivative[2][a[0]][15] == 0, Derivative[1][a[1]][15] == 1, 
   Derivative[1][b[1]][15] == 0, Derivative[1][a[2]][15] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][b[2]][15] == 0};
var = {a[0], a[1], b[1], a[2], b[2]};
```

The code to make the grid, use pdetoae and solve is:

```
points = 200;
grid = Array[# &, points, {0, inf}];
difforder = 4;
ptoafunc = pdetoae[var[y], grid, difforder];
del = #[[3 ;; -2]] &;
ae = del /@ ptoafunc@eqns;
aebc = ptoafunc@{ic0, bc};
sol = Partition[
   With[{guess = 1}, 
     FindRoot[{ae, aebc} /. {α -> 0.5}, 
      Flatten[Table[{var[[i]][y], guess}, {i, 2 nn + 1}, {y, grid}], 
       1],
      MaxIterations -> 500]][[All, -1]], points];
```

I now look at the solutions and their first and second differences:

```
diffs = Differences[#] & /@ sol;
diffs2 = Differences[#, 2] & /@ sol;
sols = Transpose[{grid, #}] & /@ sol;
dsols = Transpose[{Most[grid], #}] & /@ diffs;
dsols2 = Transpose[{Drop[grid, -2], #}] & /@ diffs2;
ListLinePlot[sols, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[dsols, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[dsols2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see the solution looks good but the first and second differences show an oscillation that is associated with the grid. Is this inevitable with a finite difference method?

I can smooth the solution using various methods but I am not sure if this is valid.  How do I get rid of the oscillations?

Thanks

Comment: @xzczd Sorry to bother you again with further questions on your excellent method.  However, if you could suggest a reason for these oscillations and a method for dealing with them that would help.

Comment: Yes, the accuracy of numerical sulutions of any finite differences or finite element solver should reduce for higher derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to choose a higher `difforder`. The following is obtained with `points = 100; difforder = 8`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The troublesome part is, `FindRoot` becomes slow when `points` get larger. (That's why I choose `points = 100` here. )

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Would it help if I reduced the order (here three) of the equations by introducing three first order equations? Does it come to the same thing in the end as a problem for `FindRoot`?

Comment: @hugh Slightly different. Your approach is amount to raising the difference order only for the high order derivatives. This might make the calculation faster because the resulting system is less intricated. If you want to have a try, you may find [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132668/1871) interesting.

Comment: Interesting post. I have just managed to use all first order equations but getting more points is making everything very slow. Another point. If I use first order equations which equations should I drop? Equations at the start or equations at the end of the grid? Does it make much difference? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @hugh Well, I should admit this is something I didn't explore much. In principle you can just use `#[[3;;-2]]&` on the equations generated from the orignal equations, but it's probably not the best way because one-sided formula is used for calculating derivative values on the boundary in this case. I think the best way is the following: use e.g. $y_1(0)=1$ (here $y_1$ represents $y'$) to replace the left boundary of auxiliary ODE $y_1'(x)=y_2(x)$.