# Convert polynomial to Chebyshev

Tags: polynomials

I want to convert a polynomial in "standard form" to Chebyshev 
form. Here's one way to do it:

```
(* My polynomial *) 

pa = Sum[a[i]*t^i, {i, 0, 5}] 

(* "standard form" coefficients of Chebyshev polynomial of same degree *) 

pb = CoefficientList[Sum[b[i]*ChebyshevT[i, t], {i, 0, 5}], t] 

(* helper variable *) 

bs = Table[b[i], {i, 0, 5}] 

Solve[Table[a[i - 1] == pb[[i]], {i, 1, 6}], bs]
```

This works, but is there a better (more efficient, more 
*Mathematica*-ish) way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say you have a polynomial:

```
f[x_] := 1 - x + 2 x^2 - 5 x^4
n = 5; (* Polynomial order + 1 *)
```

Now you have to solve a system of linear equations:

```
a = Transpose @ PadRight @ Table[CoefficientList[ChebyshevT[k - 1, x], x], {k, n}];
c = LinearSolve[a, CoefficientList[f[x], x]]
(* {1/8, -1, -3/2, 0, -5/8} *)

Sum[c[[k]] ChebyshevT[k - 1, x], {k, n}] // Expand
(* 1 - x + 2 x^2 - 5 x^4 *)
```

If getting the numerical values of coefficients is sufficient, you can use the discrete Fourier transform, which is an extremely fast method.

$\qquad T_n(x) = \cos(n \arccos x)$

```
c = 2 MapAt[#/2 &, #, 1]/Sqrt[n] & @ FourierDCT @ f @ Cos[π Range[.5, n]/n]
(* {0.125, -1., -1.5, -9.93014*10^-17, -0.625} *)

Sum[c[[k]] ChebyshevT[k - 1, x], {k, n}] // Expand // Chop
(* 1. - 1. x + 2. x^2 - 5. x^4 *)
```

P.S. The last method can be used for the Chebyshev expansion of an arbitrary function (there can be a problem with Gibbs oscillations, but that is another story).

Answer (score 7):

The matrix implicitly used for the basis conversion in ybeltukov's answer actually has a nice closed form. You can use this to perform the conversion directly, without having to use `LinearSolve[]`:

```
pcmat[n_Integer?NonNegative] := SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; j <= k && EvenQ[k - j] :> 
      Binomial[k - 1, Quotient[k - 1, 2] - Quotient[j - 1, 2]]/
      2^(k - Boole[j > 1] - 1)}, {n + 1, n + 1}]
```

Test:

```
pcmat[4].CoefficientList[1 - x + 2 x^2 - 5 x^4, x]
   {1/8, -1, -3/2, 0, -5/8}
```

---

Having the explicit basis change matrix available allows us to study the numerical stability of the conversion. In particular, we can do an analysis similar to the one in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84243), and look at the growth of the condition number of the basis change matrix for various degrees:

```
Table[Ceiling[Log10[LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[pcmat[k]]]], {k, 15}]
   {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6}
```

This says, for instance, that you can lose up to $6$ significant figures when converting a degree-$15$ polynomial in the monomial basis to Chebyshev form.

---

For completeness, here's the routine for the inverse matrix (for converting from the Chebyshev basis to the monomial basis):

```
cpmat[n_Integer?NonNegative] := 
      SparseArray[{{1, k_} /; OddQ[k] :> (-1)^Quotient[k, 2],
                   {j_, k_} /; 1 < j <= k :> Cos[(k - j) π/2] 2^(j - 2)
                   Binomial[(k + j)/2 - 2, (k - j)/2] (k - 1)/(j - 1)},
                  {n + 1, n + 1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use [Salzer's algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/355611.362548) (previously used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13681)) to perform the basis conversion:

```
poly = 1 - x + 2 x^2 - 5 x^4;
c = CoefficientList[poly, x];
n = Length[c] - 1; Remove[a];
a[0, 2] = c[[n - 1]] + c[[n + 1]]/2;
a[1, 2] = c[[n]]; a[2, 2] = c[[n + 1]]/2;
Do[
   a[0, k + 1] = c[[n - k]] + a[1, k]/2;
   a[1, k + 1] = a[0, k] + a[2, k]/2;
   Do[
      a[m, k + 1] = (a[m + 1, k] + a[m - 1, k])/2,
      {m, 2, k - 1}];
   a[k, k + 1] = a[k - 1, k]/2;
   a[k + 1, k + 1] = a[k, k]/2,
   {k, 2, n - 1}];

ccof = Table[a[m, n], {m, 0, n}]
   {1/8, -1, -3/2, 0, -5/8}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably similar to Salzer's algorithm [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) refers to, but it seemed easier to figure it out from the recurrence relation
$$T_{n+1} = 2x\,T_{n} - T_{n-1}$$
From it, we get the following identity for multiplying by $x$:
$$\eqalign{
x\, T_0 &= T_1 \cr
x\, T_{n} &= \frac{1}{2}\,T_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2}\,T_{n-1}, \quad n \ge 1\cr
}$$
From the Horner form
$$p(x) = x\, (x\, (x\, (x\, (a_n\, x+a_{n-1})+a_{n-2})+\cdots)+a_1)+a_0$$
we can see that constructing the polynomial can be done by repeated application of the identities above and the relation $a_k = a_k T_0$.
It follows that multiplying by $x$ is a linear operation represented by the matrix
$$
X=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} &  &  &  \\
 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & &  \\
  & \frac{1}{2} & 0& \ddots &  \\
  & & \ddots & \ddots & \frac{1}{2} \\
  &  &  & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
(* n x n Chebyshev multiplication operator:
    chebX[n].cs  multiplies length  n  Chebyshev series  cs  by  x  --
    the series must end in zero or the degree  n-1  term will be lost *)
chebX[n_Integer /; n >= 3] := 
  SparseArray[{{2, 1} -> 1, Band[{3, 2}] -> 1/2, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> 1/2}, {n, n}];
chebX[2] := SparseArray[{{2, 1} -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1/2}, {2, 2}];
chebX[1] := SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1}, {1, 1}];
```

J.M.'s example:

```
poly = 1 - x + 2 x^2 - 5 x^4;
p = Reverse@CoefficientList[poly, x];
n = Length[p];
X = chebX[n];
Fold[X.# + SparseArray[{1 -> #2}, n] &, SparseArray[{}, n], p] // Normal
%.Table[ChebyshevT[n, x], {n, 0, 4}]
% // Expand
(*
  {1/8, -1, -(3/2), 0, -(5/8)}                           -- Coefficients
  1/8 - x - 3/2 (-1 + 2 x^2) - 5/8 (1 - 8 x^2 + 8 x^4)   -- Chebyshev form
  1 - x + 2 x^2 - 5 x^4                                  -- Expanded power series form
*)
```

Here's a general function:

```
Clear[chebForm, chebX, chebFunc];

chebFunc[c_?VectorQ, dom_][x_] := chebFunc[c, dom, x];
chebFunc[c_?VectorQ, {a_, b_}, x_?NumericQ] := 
  ChebyshevT[Range[0, Length[c] - 1], (2 x - (a + b))/(b - a)].c;
Normal[chebFunc[c_?VectorQ, {a_, b_}, x_]] ^:= 
  ChebyshevT[Range[0, Length[c] - 1], (2 x - (a + b))/(b - a)].c;

(* Chebyshev multiplication operator (same as above) *)
chebX[n_Integer /; n >= 3] := 
  SparseArray[{{2, 1} -> 1, Band[{3, 2}] -> 1/2, 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> 1/2}, {n, n}];
chebX[2] := SparseArray[{{2, 1} -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1/2}, {2, 2}];
chebX[1] := SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1}, {1, 1}];

(* convert polynomial to Chebyshev series *)
chebForm[poly_, x_] := chebForm[poly, {x, -1, 1}];
chebForm[poly_, {x_, a_, b_}] := Module[{p, n, X},
  p = Reverse@CoefficientList[poly /. x -> (b - a)/2 x + (a + b)/2, x];
  n = Length[p];
  X = chebX[n];
  (* nested multiplication (Horner) *)
  chebFunc[Fold[X.# + SparseArray[{1 -> #2}, n] &, SparseArray[{}, n], p], {a, b}]
  ]
```

Example: (`Normal` converts the `chebFunc` to a Chebyshev series in explicit polynomial form.)

```
cp = chebForm[poly, x];
cp[x]
% // Normal
% // Expand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The Chebyshev series is particularly (numerically) accurate over the interval $[-1,1]$.  One can pass a domain $[a,b]$ that is rescaled to $[-1,1]$:

```
cp = chebForm[poly, {x, -2, 3}];
cp[x]
% // Normal
% // Expand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

in a more compact, terser way, I would say :
`Solve[Thread[Array[a, 6, 0] == pb], Array[b, 6, 0]]`
with just the notations `Array` and `Thread` thown in.
This avoids explicit (over-)use of `Table`.