# Interpolating or smoothing list plot

Tags: interpolation, smoothing

I am currently trying to interpret my FTIR data. But due to a lot of background noise, my spectrum is quite spiky and fluctuating at some points. I want to try to smoothen my function to make the peaks in the spectrum more apparent.

My code looks like this:

```
ListLinePlot[{q2, q1}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity},
PlotRange -> {{3100, 2700}, Automatic}, 
PlotLegends -> {"UV1", "PURE1"}, ImageSize -> Full, 
GridLines -> {{2870, 2960, 2925, 2850}, {}}, Black, 
Bold, FontSize -> 16], Style["Absorbance", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 16]}, 
TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14]]
```

Giving the following plot:

[image]

So I would like to make it more smooth. Any ideas on how to do this? I've tried to find something, but I only came across Interpolating, but that did not really work because my data set is not just a list of numbers.

Comment: [Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) accepts input data in various forms (input does not have to be _just a list of numbers_). If your `q1` and `q2` are lists of pairs you can use [this form](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko0dP.png) of `Interpolation`. If you post a small portion of your actual data (for example, `q1[[;;10]]` and `q2[[;;10]]`), it will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Perhaps convolving your data with a suitable kernel (Gaussian perhaps) could help.

Comment: Note that smoothing can make some peaks less apparent.  Do you have a definition for what constitutes a peak over and above the noise?  Maybe something as simple as using the functions `MovingAverage` or `MovingMedian` or `FindPeaks` will suit your needs.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115444/mathematica-interpolation-or-approximation

Answer (score 1):

I think [`LowpassFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LowpassFilter.html) should do what you want. (I can't comment yet)

**Edit:** An example of how you could use it:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x] + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}];
data2 = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], LowpassFilter[data[[All, 2]], 0.2]}];
ListPlot[{data, data2}, Joined -> True]
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add some Mathematica code to show how this works on a some "test data"?

Comment: sure, but note that there are also good examples in the documentation