# FunctionInterpolation over an open interval

Tags: interpolation, splines

I'm trying to obtain an arc-length parametrization of a spline curve as per https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8456. To do so, I need to calculate partial derivatives of such curve and then perform a `FunctionInterpolation`. The spline curve is continuous over its whole domain, but not differentiable at its knots (left-side derivatives are different from the right-side ones). Therefore, I'd need to create **several `FunctionInterpolation`s, each defined on an open interval between two consecutive knots**.

Is that possible? And if so, how? If not, how can I overcome this limitation?

Here is the actual data I'm working on:
    curve = BSplineCurve[{{198.2063059205538`,402.121623269958`},{191.2621031932776`,243.2810494404048`},{350.2070352491573`,246.3653323645185`},{307.7702781407043`,406.7480444184375`},{624.1169877141547`,382.0737810255268`},{367.1817351705904`,154.607913753287`},{408.0753377407309`,28.15231386462074`},{192.0336877673071`,89.837972346897`}}, SplineDegree -> 3, SplineKnots -> {0,0,0,0,1.`,2.`,3.`,4.`,5,5,5,5}, SplineWeights -> {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}];

```
cp = curve[[1]];
dg = curve[[2]] // Values;
kn = curve[[3]] // Values;
wg = curve[[4]] // Values;

x[t_]:=Total[Table[BSplineBasis[{dg,kn},j,t],{j,0,Length[kn]-dg-2}]*wg*cp[[All,1]]]/Table[BSplineBasis[{dg,kn},j,t],{j,0,Length[kn]-dg-2}].wg;
y[t_]:=Total[Table[BSplineBasis[{dg,kn},j,t],{j,0,Length[kn]-dg-2}]*wg*cp[[All,2]]]/Table[BSplineBasis[{dg,kn},j,t],{j,0,Length[kn]-dg-2}].wg;
f[t_]:=Sqrt[(x'[t])^2+(y'[t])^2];
```

You can see that the interpolating function has spikes (that I'm trying to avoid) at the knot values:

```
FunctionInterpolation[f[t],{t,Min[kn],Max[kn]}]//Plot[#[g]-f[g],{g,Min[kn],Max[kn]},PlotRange->Full]&
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, typo, fixed (`zzz` was supposed to be `f`)

Answer (score 6):

I've been waiting for a good problem to use [barycentric interpolation at the Gauss-Legendre points](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.0154.pdf).  It has excellent properties for analytic functions.  Here we have a piecewise analytic function, so it should be good once we have divided the interval up.  For some reason, I was having trouble getting a good result until I hit on the idea of using `NIntegrate` to subdivide the interval.

The formula for barycentric interpolation is
$$f_{IF}={\sum_j \displaystyle {\lambda_j \over x-x_j} \, f(x_j)
 \over
 \sum_j \displaystyle {\lambda_j \over x-x_j}}$$
where the weights $\lambda_j$ are given by
$$\lambda_j = \prod_{k \ne j} {1 \over x_j-x_k}\,.$$
When the nodes $x_j$ are the zeros of the Legendre polynomial $P_{n+1}$,
the weights are given by
$$\lambda_j = (-1)^j \sqrt{\left(1-x_j^2\right)\,w_j}$$
where the $w_j$ are the Gauss rule integration weights.  The nodes $x_j$ and weights $w_j$ are available in *Mathematica* in both of the following:

```
NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[n, MachinePrecision]                 (* n points & weights *)
NIntegrate`GaussBerntsenEspelidRuleData[n, MachinePrecision]  (* 2n+1 points & weights *)
```

Here then functions for constructing the Gauss-Legendre barycentric interpolation of degree `deg` of a function `f` over an interval `{a, b}`:

```
ClearAll[baryInterp, gaussLegendreInterpolation];
(* construct barycentric interpolation at the Gauss-Legendre nodes *)
gaussLegendreInterpolation[deg_Integer?Positive, f_, {a_, b_}] := 
  Module[{xj, fj, lj, wj},
   {xj, wj} = Most@NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[deg + 1, MachinePrecision];
   xj = Rescale[xj, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}];
   wj = 2 wj;
   fj = Developer`ToPackedArray[f /@ Rescale[xj, {-1, 1}, {a, b}], 
     Real];
   lj = (-1)^Range[0, deg] Sqrt[(1 - xj^2) wj];
   baryInterp[xj, fj, lj, {a, b}]
   ];

(* generic barycentric interpolation *)
baryInterp[xj_List, fj_List, lj_, {a_, b_}][x_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{xx, j, c},
   xx = Rescale[x, {a, b}, {-1, 1}];
   j = First@Nearest[xj -> "Index", xx];
   If[xx == xj[[j]],
    fj[[j]],
    c = lj/(xx - xj);
    c.fj/Total[c]
    ]
   ];
```

Let's apply it to the OP's problem.  The Gauss-Legendre interpolation converges quickly, like Gaussian quadrature.  For a function that is analytic on an interval, it pays to pick a moderately high degree.

```
nNodes = 21; (* must be odd *)
knots = Cases[f[t], BSplineBasis[{_, u_}, __] :> u, Infinity] // N // 
   Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
(*  {0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.}  *)

Clear[df, t];
df[t0_?NumericQ] := f'[t0];
NIntegrate[
   df[t], Evaluate@Flatten@{t, knots},
   Method -> {"GaussBerntsenEspelidRule", "Points" -> (nNodes + 1)/2},
   PrecisionGoal -> 12,
   IntegrationMonitor :> ((intervals = #@ "Boundaries" & /@ #) &)
 ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.36377, Null}  *)

Flatten[intervals, 1]  (* intervals used by NIntegrate to approx. int(f) *)
(*
{{1.5, 2.}, {0.5, 1.}, {0., 0.5}, {2., 2.5}, {2.75, 3.}, {3.5, 4.},
 {4.25, 4.5}, {2.5, 2.75}, {3., 3.25}, {4., 4.25}, {3.25, 3.5},
 {4.5, 4.75}, {1., 1.5}, {4.75, 5.}}
*)

(* construct a Piecwise function of interpolations *)
ClearAll[fIF];  
fIF[t_?NumericQ] = Piecewise[
   {gaussLegendreInterpolation[nNodes, f, #][t], 
      First@# <= t < Last@#} & /@ Flatten[intervals, 1]
   ];

(* Plot the relative error. Quite often it is accurate to nearly machine precision *)
Plot[{RealExponent@$MachineEpsilon, (fIF[t] - f[t])/f[t] // RealExponent},
 {t, 0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> {-18, 0},
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Update*

Here's a way to convert the above to a built-in form of [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).  It is based on [chebInterpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103397/chebyshev-approximation/114065#114065).

```
ClearAll[chebdeval, chebInterpolation, chebSeries];
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13645/small-issue-with-chebyshev-derivative-approximation/13681#13681 *)
chebdeval[coeff_List, x_] := 
  Module[{m = Length[coeff], d, e, f, j, u, v, w}, w = v = 0;
   f = e = 0;
   Do[d = 2 (x e + v) - f;
    f = e; e = d;
    u = 2 x v - w + coeff[[j]];
    w = v; v = u;, {j, m, 2, -1}];
   {x v - w + First[coeff], x e + v - f}];

(* Constructs a piecewise InterpolatingFunction, 
 * whose interpolating units are Chebyshev series c1 *)
(* data0 = {{x0,x1},c1},..} *)
chebInterpolation::usage = 
  "chebInterpolation[data:{{{x0,x1},c1},..}] constructs a piecewise \
InterpolatingFunction, whose interpolating units are Chebyshev series \
c1 on the interval {x0, x1}";
chebInterpolation[data0 : {{{_, _}, _List} ..}] := 
  Module[{data = Sort@data0, domain1, coeffs1, domain, grid, ngrid, 
    coeffs, order, y0, yp0},
   domain1 = data[[1, 1]];
   coeffs1 = data[[1, 2]];
   domain = List @@ Interval @@ data[[All, 1]];
   {y0, yp0} = (Last@domain - First@domain)/2 chebdeval[coeffs1, First@domain];
   grid = Union @@ data[[All, 1]];
   ngrid = Length@grid;
   coeffs = PadRight[data[[All, 2]], Automatic, 0.];
   order = Length[coeffs[[1]]] - 1;
   InterpolatingFunction[
     domain,
     {5, 1, order, {ngrid}, {order}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False},
     {grid},                          (* if[[3]] *)
     {{y0, yp0}} ~Join~ coeffs,       (* if[[4]] *)
     {{{{1}}~Join~Partition[Range@ngrid, 2, 1] ~Join~ {{ngrid - 1, ngrid}},
       {Automatic} ~Join~ ConstantArray[ChebyshevT, ngrid]}}
     ] /; Length[domain] == 1
   ];

chebSeries[f_, {a_, b_}, n_] := Module[{x, y, c},
   x = Rescale[Sin[Pi/2*Range[N@n, -N@n, -2]/n], {-1, 1}, {a, b}];
   y = f /@ x;                       (* function values at Chebyshev points *)
   c = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[y, 1];   (* get coeffs from values *)
   c[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;                (* adjust first & last coeffs *)
   c
   ];
```

OP's example:

```
foo = {#, chebSeries[gaussLegendreInterpolation[nNodes, f, #], #, nNodes]} & /@
   Flatten[intervals, 1] // chebInterpolation
```

The error is nearly the same:

```
Plot[{RealExponent@$MachineEpsilon, (foo[t] - f[t])/f[t] // 
   RealExponent},
 {t, 0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> {-18, 0},
 Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: There is a built-in, but *undocumented* routine for barycentric interpolation. In your notation, one would call it as ``f = Statistics`Library`BarycentricInterpolation[xj, fj, Weights -> lj]; f[x]``

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  And `f[x, 1]` yields the first derivative. There's good, general stuff in ``Statistics`Library`` that should accessible to users at the ``System` `` level.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the easiest way is to use `NDSolve`, with an event to restart integration at the knots:

```
Clear[ff, t];
df[t0_?NumericQ] := f'[t0];
fIF = NDSolveValue[
   {ff'[t] == df[t], ff[0] == f[0],
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, "RestartIntegration"]},
   ff, {t, 0, 5},
   (*Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 15},*)
   (*PrecisionGoal -> 10,*)
   InterpolationOrder -> All];
```

The optional options result in a higher quality interpolation, but it takes over a minute.

Plot of the relative error:

```
Plot[(fIF[t] - f[t])/f[t] // RealExponent, {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> {-20, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

(This is too long for a comment.)

Note that all your weights are set to `1`, and so you do not need to construct the full NURBS expression (recall that the B-spline basis functions form a partition of unity); thus, the polynomial case will suffice:

```
cp = {{198.2063059205538, 402.121623269958}, {191.2621031932776, 243.2810494404048},
      {350.2070352491573, 246.3653323645185}, {307.7702781407043, 406.7480444184375},
      {624.1169877141547, 382.0737810255268}, {367.1817351705904, 154.607913753287},
      {408.0753377407309, 28.15231386462074}, {192.0336877673071, 89.837972346897}};
d = 3;
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5};
wts = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

x[t_] = Table[BSplineBasis[{d, knots}, j, t], {j, 0, Length[knots] - d - 2}].cp[[All, 1]];
y[t_] = Table[BSplineBasis[{d, knots}, j, t], {j, 0, Length[knots] - d - 2}].cp[[All, 2]];
```

---

Having gotten that out of the way, here is another proposal: let `Plot[]` do the sampling for you, and then perform a Hermite interpolation of the arclength derivative. Here's one way to go about it:

```
f[t_] := Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2]

(* sampling; adjust PlotPoints or MaxRecursion as needed *)
pts = First[Cases[Normal[Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 5}]], Line[l_] :> l, ∞]];
(* ensure endpoints are present *)
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[knots];
pts = DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{xmin, f[xmin]}} ~Join~ pts ~Join~ {{xmax, f[xmax]}}, First]

(* build Hermite interpolant *)
ff = Interpolation[{{#1}, #2, f'[#1]} & @@@ pts, Method -> "Hermite"];
```

Compare:

```
{Plot[{f[t], ff[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], AbsoluteThickness[1]}],
 Plot[f[t] - ff[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: real and interpolated arclength derivative]