# Find good polynomial fit of square root

Tags: fitting

I would like to find a good polynomial fit of the square root.
I tried the following:

```
m = Fit[Table[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, Pi}], {x, x^2}, x]
Plot[{Sqrt[x], m}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

But the results are not convincing:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Square root is a classic example of a function that polynomials don't fit well. It has a branch point at zero, something no polynomial can reproduce.

Comment: @JohnDoty is quite right.  The gradient at zero is infinite, which cannot be matched with a polynomial. Can you explain why you want to do this?  A polynomial approximation of `Sqrt[1+x]` could work well.

Comment: @JohnDoty I agreee, but there ought to be a better solution than mine, right ? What other non polynomial could be used ?

Comment: @james try
`m = Fit[Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, .01}], {1, x, x^2}, x]`
`Plot[{Sqrt[x], m}, {x, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi This is actually pretty good ! Thanks !

Comment: As @RohitNamjoshi pointed implicitly pointed out, you were performing a fit only on points 0, 1, 2, and 3. Here's another method of over an interval: `With[{fit = a x^2 + b x + c /. Last@Minimize[Integrate[(Sqrt[x] - (a x^2 + b x + c))^2, {x, 0, Pi}], {a, b, c}]}, Plot[{Sqrt[x], fit}, {x, 0, Pi}]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Gauss-Legendre interpolation, adapted from [FunctionInterpolation over an open interval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166132/functioninterpolation-over-an-open-interval/166172#166172):

```
ClearAll[gaussLegendreInterpolation];
(*construct barycentric interpolation at the Gauss-Legendre nodes*)
gaussLegendreInterpolation[deg_Integer?Positive, f_, {a_, b_}] := 
  Module[{xj, fj, lj, wj},
   {xj, wj} = Most@NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[deg + 1, 18 + 1.5 deg];
   wj = 2 wj;
   lj = (-1)^Range[0, deg] Sqrt[(1 - Rescale[xj, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}]^2) wj];
   xj = Rescale[xj, {0, 1}, {a, b}];
   fj = f /@ xj;
   Statistics`Library`BarycentricInterpolation[xj, fj, Weights -> lj]];
```

Degree 2 interpolant:

```
sqrt = gaussLegendreInterpolation[2, Sqrt, {0, Pi}][x] // Simplify // N
(*  0.358018 + 0.698352 x - 0.0817347 x^2  *)

Plot[{Sqrt[x], sqrt}, {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> Precision@sqrt]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Degree 20 interpolant:

```
sqrt = gaussLegendreInterpolation[20, Sqrt, {0, Pi}][x] // Simplify // N
(*
  0.0547549 + 4.91465 x - 43.8281 x^2 + 333.68 x^3 - 1747.49 x^4 + 
   6419.58 x^5 - 17104.3 x^6 + 34004. x^7 - 51553.3 x^8 + 60568.2 x^9 - 
   55757.4 x^10 + 40489.7 x^11 - 23253.5 x^12 + 10544. x^13 - 
   3750.35 x^14 + 1033.25 x^15 - 215.885 x^16 + 33.0421 x^17 - 
   3.49217 x^18 + 0.227653 x^19 - 0.00689549 x^20
*)    

Plot[{Sqrt[x], sqrt}, {x, 0, Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> Precision@sqrt]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that as you go higher in degree, if the polynomial is put into power-basis form as above, the polynomial suffers from catastrophic numerical errors, unless high precision is used.  Omit the `// N` to use high precision.  Using barycentric interpolation is more stable than converting to the power basis, but I chose the above form because the OP seemed interested in getting the formula.  The barycentric formula is a bit of a mess and looks like a rational function.  Indeed you get divide-by-zero errors unless you use [`baryInterp[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166132/functioninterpolation-over-an-open-interval/166172#166172).

Comment: It occurs to me one can use `Interpolation` on the Gauss-Legendre points, instead of using `BarycentricInterpolation[]`, if the power-basis form is desired. (I started with the BC interp. in mind for numerical reasons, but as I thought through my answer, I clung to BC even after it need evaporated.)

Answer (score 5):

Padé (rational) approximations are much better.

```
asqrt[x] = PadeApproximant[Sqrt[x], {x, 1, 2}]
(* (1 + 5/4 (-1 + x) + 5/16 (-1 + x)^2)/(1 + 3/4 (-1 + x) + 1/16 (-1 + x)^2) *)
Plot[{Sqrt[x], asqrt[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Even more snug rational fit: `Module[{f}, 
 f[a_?NumericQ, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Quiet@NIntegrate[(Sqrt[x] - x (a - x)/(b x^2 + c x + d))^2, {x, 0, 
     Pi}]; Plot[{Sqrt[x], 
   x (a - x)/(b x^2 + c x + d) /. 
    Last@NMinimize[f[a, b, c, d], {a, b, c, d}, Reals]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
  Evaluated -> True]]` - here I do assume that value of the function is zero at zero, of course.

Comment: @kirma This is great ! How do I get the resulting function ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: @james `Module[{f}, f[a_?NumericQ, b_, c_, d_] := Quiet@NIntegrate[(Sqrt[x] - x (a - x)/(b x^2 + c x + d))^2, {x, 0, Pi}]; Plot[{Sqrt[x], x (a - x)/(b x^2 + c x + d) /. Last@NMinimize[f[a, b, c, d], {a, b, c, d}, Reals]` evaluates to `((-0.6450108179399511 - x)*x)/(-0.1008496912186526 - 1.2894051380615201*x - 0.2625364225597352*x^2)`

Comment: Frankly I don't know why I picked the odd form of `(a - x)` instead of `(x + a)`  or `(x - a)`, but `NMinimize` doesn't complain about such style details...

Comment: And, if you want to keep going down this rabbit hole, there's the `FunctionApproximations` package.

Comment: @james Eh. What I really meant to say was that `Module[{eqn, f}, eqn = x (x - a)/(b x^2 + c x + d); 
 f[a_?NumericQ, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Quiet@NIntegrate[(Sqrt[x] - eqn)^2, {x, 0, Pi}]; 
 eqn /. Last@NMinimize[f[a, b, c, d], {a, b, c, d}, Reals]]` evaluates to `(x (0.644999 + x))/(0.100847 + 1.2894 x + 0.262538 x^2)`.

Comment: @kirma Thank you very much ! This helps a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Quantile Regression fit of Chebyshev polynomials through the package "MonadicQuantileRegression.m". See [this blog post](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/) for details.

```
sqPoints = Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 1/2, 8, 0.1}];
ListPlot[sqPoints]

Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]

p =
  QRMonUnit[sqPoints]⟹
   QRMonQuantileRegressionFit[20, 0.5]⟹
   QRMonPlot[]⟹
   QRMonErrorPlots⟹
   QRMonErrors⟹QRMonEchoFunctionValue["Relative errors summary:", RecordsSummary /@ # &];
```

[image]

```
qFunc = (p⟹QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions)[0.5];

Simplify[qFunc[x]]

(* 27.05 - 245.125 x + 1011.11 x^2 - 2479.16 x^3 + 4080.66 x^4 - 4812.07 x^5 + 
 4233.13 x^6 - 2853.77 x^7 + 1501.85 x^8 - 624.791 x^9 + 207.112 x^10 - 
 54.9287 x^11 + 11.6595 x^12 - 1.97386 x^13 + 0.264376 x^14 - 
 0.0276295 x^15 + 0.00220351 x^16 - 0.000129425 x^17 + 5.27363*10^-6 x^18 - 
 1.3307*10^-7 x^19 + 1.56554*10^-9 x^20 *)
```