# Difference in interpolated data derivative and analytic function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I am trying to calculate the derivative of interpolated data but it behaves differently from the analytic solution. Detailed code that I have used follows:

```
 \[Gamma]w = 70.0*10^-3;(*SR in N/m*)\[Rho] = 1000; c = 3*10^8; g = 9.8;
  we1 = 7*10^-6;(*beam waist*)n = 1.33; P0 = 4.0; rng = 50*10^-6;
 lc = Sqrt[\[Gamma]w/(\[Rho]*g)]; P0 = 4; we1 = 
  7*10^-6; P1 = (P0/(\[Gamma]w*c*Pi))*((n - 1)/(n + 1));
  f[r_] := 7*P1*BesselK[0, r/lc];
  lst2 = Table[{r, f[r]}, {r, we1, rng, rng/1000}]; h2 = 
   Interpolation[lst2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
   pA = Plot[{h2[r]}, {r, we1, rng}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True];
  pIn = Plot[{f[r]}, {r, we1, rng}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True];
   Show[{pA, pIn}](*height*);
    A[r_] := h2''[r] + 1/r*h2'[r];(*Interpolation*)
     A2 = D[f[r], {r, 2}] + 1/r*D[f[r], r];(*Analytic*)A3 = D[A2, {r, 
      1}];
     plots = Plot[{A'[r], A3}, {r, we1, rng/1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}}, 
    GridLines -> {{we1, 2 we1}, {0}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
   PlotLegends -> {"Interpolation (A'[r])", "Analytic (A3)"}]
    [![plots][1]][1]
```

Comment: You are using a fairly high interpolation order, which makes the derivatives numerically unstable. I would suggest using a smaller `InterpolationOrder`. But generally, what you are trying to do is numerically unstable. Better to compute the derivatives straight from the data instead of going through an interpolation.

Comment: @Roman, Thanks. I also tried with a small InterpolationOrder.  Could you suggest how to compute derivative straight from the data?

Comment: The easiest way to compute numerical derivatives directly from the data is probably to set `InterpolationOrder -> 1` and let Mathematica take care of the details. In this way it will interpolate linearly between data points, thus effectively using the [finite-differences method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) of numerical differentiation. In general, to compute $n^{\text{th}}$ derivatives you should use an interpolation of oder $n$ (but not higher).

Comment: Thanks @ Roman, I tried with this code ( lst2 = Table[{r, f[r]}, {r, we1, rng, rng/1000}]; h2 =  Interpolation[lst2, InterpolationOrder -> 1] ) but I found huge difference in interpolated data plot and analytic one.

Comment: It might be easier to help if the code were posted in a more readable way (e.g. no more than line of code in a line, that is, start each line of code at the left margin).

Comment: `Plot[f'[r], {r, we1, rng}]` works pretty well and fast. Why not use it?

Comment: Also there is the recently added Wolfram Function Repository function [ListD](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ListD). It might give reasonable results. And the web page has examples that might give ideas for related methods involving local smoothing.

Comment: Thanks@Daniel suggesting nice ListD Repository function. I want to calculate mean curvature which is given by A[r_] := h2''[r] + 1/r*h2'[r], I can calculate h2'' and h2' but how to include 1/r.

Comment: You might have to reduce the size of the set by one or two, e.g. by taking pairwise averages or weighted sums of consecutive triples. By the way "@Daniel"  did not reach me even though I'm the only Daniel in this chain of comments. I guess you need to add the last name (no space though).

Answer (score 3):

`InterpolationOrder -> 1` means the first derivative will be discontinuous (piecewise constant) and the second and third derivatives will be zero. You need an interpolation order higher than 3 to get a continuous result.

```
h2 = Interpolation[lst2, InterpolationOrder -> 7]; 
A[r_] := h2''[r] + 1/r*h2'[r];(*Interpolation*)
A2 = 
 D[f[r], {r, 2}] + 1/r*D[f[r], r];(*Analytic*)
A3 = D[A2, {r, 1}];
plots = Plot[{A'[r], A3}, {r, we1, rng/1}(*,PlotRange->All*), 
  Frame -> True(*,PlotRange->All*), Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}}, 
  GridLines -> {{we1, 2 we1}, {0}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
  PlotLegends -> {"Interpolation (A'[r])", "Analytic (A3)"}]
```

[image]

Still a bit of noise...

*P.S.*

Using `chebInterpolation` and `chebSeries` from
[FunctionInterpolation over an open interval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166132/functioninterpolation-over-an-open-interval/166172#166172),
we also get a pretty good approximation, which is much less noisy:

```
h2 = chebInterpolation[{{N@{we1, rng}, 
    chebSeries[f, N@{we1, rng}, 64][[;; -12]]}}]
```

This is nearly equivalent:

```
lst2 = Table[{r, f[r]}, {r, 
   Rescale[
    Sin[Pi/2. Range[-64, 64, 2]/64], {-1, 1}, {we1, rng}]}]; 
h2 = Interpolation[lst2, InterpolationOrder -> All]
```

Note: The function `A3` seems to lose about 7 digits of precision due to subtractive cancellation.  (Based on evaluating a high-precision `A3` on arbitrary precision input and observing the precision loss.)

Comment: Yeah, that precision loss will be difficult to avoid. Offhand I do not know if smoothing or spectral methods can do better or, if so, by how much.