# How to use fast Fourier transforms (FFT) to calculate derivatives of a function?

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Suppose we have a function numerically defined at pseudospectral collocation points

```
nx = 12;
x = -N[Table[Cos[(j Pi)/nx], {j, 0, nx}]]
(* -> {-1., -0.965926, -0.866025, -0.707107, -0.5, -0.258819, 0., 0.258819, 0.5, 0.707107, 0.866025, 0.965926, 1.} *)
```

Take the following `f` as an example

```
f = Exp[x] + x^2;
(* -> {1.36788, 1.31364, 1.17062, 0.993069, 0.856531, 0.83895, 1., 1.36239, 1.89872, 2.52811, 3.12744, 3.56023, 3.71828} *)
```

We want to calculate the derivative of `f` with respect to `x`. This can be achieved by multiplying `f` by the following differentiation matrix `dx`

```
dx = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]["DifferentiationMatrix"];
dx.f
(* -> {-1.63212, -1.55122, -1.31143, -0.921145, -0.393469, 0.254325, 1., 1.81304, 2.64872, 3.44233, 4.10949, 4.55907, 4.71828} *)
```

In the tutorial [The Numerical Method of Lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html),

> For pseudospectral derivatives, which can be computed using fast Fourier transforms, it may be faster to use the differentiation matrix for small size, but ultimately, on a larger grid, the better complexity and numerical properties of the FFT make this the much better choice.

How to obtain pseudospectral derivatives of the above function `f` by FFT?

Comment: Related: [Chebyshev coefficients `cc`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89692/4999) and [`chebdeval`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13681/4999)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x, f, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]
```

Or

```
func = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]
func[f]
```

Comment: This is significantly faster than `dx.f` for large `nx`, implying that `func[f]` uses FFT internally.