# Convert Matlab code for Fourier transform equivalently into Mathematica

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

I have a Matlab-style code that uses Fourier transform efficiently. Here is the function which defines a differentiation matrix `D`, where `N` denotes the modes number and `kk` is the wavenumber.

```
function [A,B,D,x]=func(N)
dxx=2*pi/N;x=dxx*((1:N)');
kk=[-N/2+1:N/2]';
C=diag(1i*kk);
A=exp(1i*x*kk');
B=exp(-1i*kk*x')/N;
D=A*(C*B);
```

In the main program, the differentiation matrix `D` can be used easily as an operator. For example, consider a function `y(x)`. It uses a couple of lines to calculate the 1st- to 3rd-order derivatives.

```
N=64;
[A,B,D,x]=func(N);

D1=real(D);
D2=real(D^2);
D3=real(D^3);

Dy=D1*y;
D2y=D2*y;
D3y=D3*y;
```

I want to convert it exactly equivalently into Mathematica. I note that Mathematica provides the functions `FourierTransform` and `FourierCoefficient`, however, I found it has various parameter values for several different conventions, which is confusing. Can anyone please help to convert it as Mathematica code, and if you could give an example, it will be very helpful!

**Update**

Thanks for the help of @J. M.'s persistent exhaustion and @user293787, I can calculate the 1st- and 2nd-order derivatives, but when using the code to calculate the 3rd-order derivative, the error is too large to be acceptable. I also tried use more modes with $n=256$, but the computational time became longer and the result became worse. Can you help to improve it? Thank you very much!

```
f3d[n_] := Module[{kk = Range[-n/2 + 1, n/2], x = 2*\[Pi]*Range[n]/n}, 
  Exp[I*KroneckerProduct[x, kk]].DiagonalMatrix[(I kk)^3].(Exp[-I*KroneckerProduct[kk, x]]/n)]

n = 128; (*n = 256;*)

(*an exmaple*)
f[x_] := Sin[x] Cos[3 x] + Sin[4 x];
vals = Table[N[f[x], 20], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/(n - 1)}];
dddf = D[f[x], {x, 3}];
dddvals = Re[N[f3d[n], 20]].vals;
dddvalsTrue = Table[N[dddf, 20], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/(n - 1)}];

thirdDplot = ListLinePlot[{vals, dddvals, dddvalsTrue}, DataRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> {"original func", "diff matrix", "Exact derivative"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Concerning your Update: Your may have to take `{x,-\[Pi],\[Pi]-2 \[Pi]/n,2 \[Pi]/n}` in your tables, or something like that. But maybe this is getting out of hand here, I think @J.M. answered your original question.

Comment: @user293787 did you mean the upper bounds of both two `Table` in my update should be modified. Could you explain a little?

Comment: I changed two things, upper bound and stepsize. Why? In your Update-code the first `x`-value is $-\pi$ and the second is $+\pi$, which is the same point in a $2\pi$-periodic setting. Also, the stepsize must match the stepsize that you use in `Exp[I*KroneckerProduct[x, kk]]` which is $2\pi/n$.

Comment: Why not ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative``?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182295/1871

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that link @xzczd, I have read that document for a whole day. According to my understand, when using `Pseudospectral` we should use a mesh with uniform nodes. However, in that link the author of that post used a non-uniform mesh. Could please write a short answer to show how to use your function `func = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, x,  DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"]` to calculate the 3rd-order derivative of the example in the **update** of my post? Thank you again!

Comment: ``grid = N@Range[-Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/25];
val = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[3, grid, f@grid, 
  DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral", PeriodicInterpolation -> True]; 
ListPlot[{grid, val}\[Transpose]]~Show~Plot[f'''[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]`` "when using `Pseudospectral` we should use a mesh with uniform nodes" Yes, but **only if** `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`. Otherwise we need the **Chebyshev-Gauss-Lobatto** grid. Please read the document more carefully.

Answer (score 6):

The code provided by the OP is actually pretty straightforward to translate:

```
fdm[n_] := Module[{kk = Range[-n/2 + 1, n/2], x = 2 π Range[n]/n},
    Exp[I KroneckerProduct[x, kk]] . DiagonalMatrix[I kk] .
    (Exp[-I KroneckerProduct[kk, x]]/n)]
```

where the matrix corresponding to `D` in the original MATLAB code is returned. (If you want to return the other stuff as well, I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how to modify the function above.)

With that, here's a demo of how to use it as a differentiation matrix:

```
(* some periodic function *)
vals = Table[N[Sin[x] Cos[3 x] + Sin[4 x], 20], {x, -π, π, 2 π/(64 - 1)}];
(* estimated derivative from the differentiation matrix *)
dvals = Re[N[fdm[64], 20]] . vals;
(* true derivative for comparison *)
dvalsTrue = Table[N[-Cos[2 x] + 6 Cos[4 x], 20], {x, -π, π, 2 π/(64 - 1)}];

ListLinePlot[{vals, dvals, dvalsTrue}, DataRange -> {-π, π}, 
             PlotLegends -> {"original", "diff matrix", "true derivative"}]
```

[image: a function and its derivatives]

Comment: Hi, I use `f2d[n_] :=Module[{kk = Range[-n/2 + 1, n/2], x = 2 \[Pi] Range[n]/n}, 
  Exp[2*I KroneckerProduct[x, kk]].DiagonalMatrix[-kk^2].(Exp[-2* I KroneckerProduct[kk, x]]/n)]` to produce the 2nd-derivation, which however gives incorrect result, please correct me, thank you!

Comment: @user95273 Replace `Exp[2*I...]` by `Exp[I...]`, and replace `Exp[-2*I...]` by `Exp[-I...]`.

Comment: @user293787 thank you! it seems `DiagonalMatrix[I kk]` controls the derivative order. I tried `DiagonalMatrix[(I kk)^3]` for the 3rd-derivative, but the result looks incorrect. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @J. M.'s persistent exhaustion, by default, MATLAB uses 16 digits of precision, in order to obtain an exactly the same reuslt, does it mean I should use N[..., 16] for 16-digit precision? Thank you!

Comment: @user95273 Take @J.M.'s code for one derivative, which uses a product of three matrices, and then only change the matrix in the middle, but do not change the first and last matrix. In the `f2d` code in your comment, you also changed the first and last matrix, by introducing extra factors of `2` compared to @J.M.'s code, but that is not what you want. Another possibility is `f2dalternative[n_]:=MatrixPower[fdm[n],2]`.