# Getting error NDSolve::ndsz from my ODE

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, nonlinear

I'm trying to figure out why I am consistently getting singularity error when I'm trying to solve an ODE using `NDSolve`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
EEr = 0.5*((1 + u'[#1])^2/(1 + om*con[#1])^(2/3) - 1) &; 
EEt = 0.5*((1 + u[#1])^2/(1 + om*con[#1])^(2/3) - 1) &;

Pr = (1 + om*con[#1])^(1/3)*Ev*((1 + v)/v*EEr[#1] + EEt[#1])*(1 +u'[#1]) &;
Pt = (1 + om*con[#1])^(1/3)*Ev*(EEr[#1] + (1 + v)/v*EEt[#1])*(1 + u[#1]/#1) &;

EE = 80*10^9; 
v = 0.25; 
om = 5*10^-5; 
Ev = EE*v/(1 + v)/(1 - 2 v); 
R = 1; 
con = (1 +1000 #1) &; 
rs = $MachineEpsilon;

equ = {Pr'[r] + (Pr[r] - Pt[r])/r == 0, u[rs] == rs, Pr[1] == 0};

sol = 
  NDSolve[equ, {u}, {r, rs, 1},
    Method -> 
      {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {u[rs] == rs, u'[rs] == rs}}];
```

Evaluating the above code produces a host of errors of the form

> NDSolve::ndsz: At r == 2.220446049*10^-16 , step size is effectively zero; 
>   singularity or stiff system suspected

To be clear, the equation itself is solvable, all I need is to avoid the singular point and any tips will be very appreciated!

Comment: Check what you posted here because I am getting a NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function u appears with no arguments. error.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I've changed the code and hope this won't disturb you

Comment: Is this Prandtl number Pr?

Comment: No, it's just a ordinary symbol and the function means the Piola-Kirchhoff stress

Comment: The changes `rs = Sqrt@$MachineEpsilon` and `Pr[1]/Ev == 0` get rid of the error.  But maybe the solution is not good enough?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works. However, the numerical error near the singularity is relatively large, is there any chance to improve it? Thanks again!

Comment: From the approximate solution, it looks like `u'[r]` goes to infinity at `r == 0`. A large error is somewhat expected (and even the error computed by `NDSolve` is approximate and probably subject to large errors near `r == 0` as well). I don't have time to investigate, but there are two avenues that occur to me: (1) Come up with a better BC than `u[rs] == rs` and possibly use a higher `WorkingPrecision` to reduce rounding error. (2) Find a locally exact solution at `r == 0` and use `NDSolve` to integrate the difference. [Site tip: Use @MichaelE2 to make sure I'm notified of your reply.]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this really helps me a lot. You are very kindness and hope you enjoy the wonderful life!@MichaelE2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the issues, including ones implied in [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185066/getting-error-ndsolvendsz-from-my-ode/185110#comment482643_185066):

- Increasing round-off error as $r \rightarrow 0$.
- Increasing stiffness as $r \rightarrow 0$.
- Poor scaling due to large coefficients.
- Starting integration at the stiff boundary $r \approx 0$.

In my comments I suggested not getting too close to `r == 0`, rescaling the BC `Pr[1]/Ev == 0`, and possible increasing `WorkingPrecision` would help solve the BVP. Here I'll show another approach by starting the integration at the stabler boundary condition.

Generally, one should expect it to be easier to start the integration at the boundary where there is no singularity (or numerics issues arising from one). The trouble is finding good starting initial conditions.  One approach to BVP is to use to use `FindRoot` to find the Chebyshev series of a function that satisfies the BVP at the Chebyshev collocation points.  The BCs are easy to implement, even the one at the singularity `r == 0`.  One the one hand, this is not a particularly good example for the approach because of the singularity and numeric issue; other the other hand, with just 33 points, we quickly get a decent approximation that yields good starting points for `u[1]` and `u'[1]`.  To implement this approach I modified [J.M.'s chebdeval[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13681/4999) to return, the function, derivative, and second derivative values. (It also returns the input `x` to make the code in `residual[]` simpler.  A bit of a kludge, I guess.)

Another technique I use is to use `Solve` to rearrange an equation, so that it is better scaled.  For instance, `Solve[ODE, u''[r]]` yields a result that can be put in the form `u''[r] == RHS` such that the error `u''[r] - RHS` is scaled such that the difference can be compared to `u''[r]`. which is the value `NDSolve` is computing from the `ODE`.  Since `NDSolve` does this internally, it is not important for it, but it turns out to be helpful for `FindRoot`.  Similarly we can rescale the BC at `r == 1` with `Solve[Pr[1] == 0, u[1]]`, although because of the nonlinear nature of `Pr[1]`, it is more convenient here to solve for `(1 + u[1])^2`.  `NDSolve` does not do this, so we have to do it in the call to `NDSolve[]`.

Utility definitions and functions:

```
Clear[equ];
equ[] := Pr'[r] + (Pr[r] - Pt[r])/r == 0;  (* Basic ODE *)
equ[rs_, re_: 1] := {                      (* BVP *)
   equ[],
   u[rs] == Sqrt@rs,                       (* BC near r == 0 *)
   (1 + u[1])^2 == C[0] /. First@Solve[    (* Effectively rescales BC at r == 1 *)
      Rationalize[Rationalize@Pr[1] == 0, 0] /. (1 + u[1])^2 -> C[0], 
      C[0]]};
reduced = (Subtract @@ First@First@Solve[equ[], u''[r]]); (* Rescales ODE *)
error = reduced/(1*^-8 + Abs[u''[r]]); (* err rel to u''[r] when u''[r] > 10^-8 *)

(* computes {F, F', F'', x} of a Chebyshev series for F over {a,b} *)
Clear[chebdeval];
chebdeval[cof_List, x_, a_: 0, b_: 1] :=
  Module[{f0, f1, f2, j, p0, p1, p2, q0, q1, q2, t, dtdx},
   t = (2 x - a - b)/(-a + b); dtdx = 2/(b - a);
   f2 = f1 = 0;    (* f = F *)
   p2 = p1 = 0;    (* p = F' *)
   q2 = q1 = 0;    (* q = F'' *)
   Do[
    q0 = 2 (t q1 + 2 p1) - q2;
    q2 = q1; q1 = q0;
    p0 = 2 (t p1 + f1) - p2; 
    p2 = p1; p1 = p0;
    f0 = 2 t f1 - f2 + cof[[j]];
    f2 = f1; f1 = f0
    , {j, Length[cof], 2, -1}];
   {t f1 - f2 + First[cof], dtdx (t p1 + f1 - p2), dtdx^2 (t q1 + 2 p1 - q2), x}
   ];

(* adds BC u[0]==0 to coefficient list add prepending the zero-order
   Chebyshev coefficient c[0] to coefficient array c[1], c[2],...  *)
addbc = Prepend[#, ((-1)^Range[0, Length@# - 1]).#] &;

(* computes residual errors of the ode at collocation nodes *)
Clear[residual];
residual[c_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), nodes_] :=
  With[{coeff = addbc[c]},  (* add BC at r == 0 *)
   Append[
    reduced /. 
     Thread[{u[r], u'[r], u''[r], r} -> chebdeval[coeff, nodes[[2 ;; -2]]]],
    Pr[1]/Ev /.             (* add BC at r == 1 *)
     Thread[{u[1], u'[1], u''[1], r} -> chebdeval[coeff, nodes[[-1]]]]
    ]
   ];
```

Carrying out the solution:

```
(* construct Chebyshev solution *)
Block[{n = 32},
 nodes = Sin[Pi/2 Range[-N@n, n, 2]/n];
 cc32 = coeff /. FindRoot[  (* Find Chebyshev series that satisfies ODE at nodes *)
    residual[coeff, (nodes + 1)/2] == ConstantArray[0, Length@nodes - 1],
    {coeff, ConstantArray[0, Length@nodes - 1]},
    PrecisionGoal -> 10];
 ]

(* Use Chebyshev sol. for "StartingInitialConditions" at r == 1 for NDSolve *)
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock[Infinity]};
Block[{rs = $MachineEpsilon, wp = 32},
  rs = SetPrecision[rs, wp];
  sol = First@NDSolve[
     Rationalize[Rationalize@equ[rs], 0], {u}, {r, rs, 1},
     Method -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
         {{u[1], u'[1]} == Rationalize[chebdeval[addbc@cc32, 1][[;; 2]], 0]}, 
       Method -> Automatic},
     WorkingPrecision -> wp, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
     InterpolationOrder -> All]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Error and visualizations:

```
NIntegrate @@ {
   SetPrecision[error, 24]^2 /. sol,
   Flatten@
    {r, Sort[Join[
       u@"Grid" /. sol,
       {{r}} /. FindRoot[u''[r] /. sol, {r, 0.22}, WorkingPrecision -> 24]]]},
   MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 16, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 24} // Sqrt
(*  9.43592806141403019272207*10^-7  *)

Plot @@ {error /. sol // RealExponent, Flatten@{r, u@"Domain" /. sol},
   PlotPoints -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1/4}
```

[image]

```
Plot[{First@chebdeval[addbc@cc32, x], u[x] /. sol}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[6], AbsoluteThickness[3]}]
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I am just in the first grade for my doctor degree  and your code is a bit complicated to me. However, I will continue to work hard, and your professional attitude motivates me to discover a broader science world. Your words mean a lot to me and thanks again. @Michael E2

Answer (score 2):

Michael explained almost everything. I will add a few words. In this problem, the main source of errors is a large parameter `Ev = 3.2 * 10 ^ 10` by which all parts of the equation are multiplied, but on which the solution does not depend. We reduce this parameter, and we solve the equation with high precision, for which we present all parameters in a rational form

```
EEr = 1/2*((1 + u'[#1])^2/(1 + om*con[#1])^(2/3) - 1) &;
EEt = 1/2*((1 + u[#1])^2/(1 + om*con[#1])^(2/3) - 1) &;

Pr = (1 + om*con[#1])^(1/3)*((1 + v)/v*EEr[#1] + EEt[#1])*(1 + 
      u'[#1]) &;
Pt = (1 + om*con[#1])^(1/3)*(EEr[#1] + (1 + v)/v*EEt[#1])*(1 + 
      u[#1]/#1) &;

EE = 80*10^9;
v = 1/4;
om = 5*10^-5;
Ev = EE*v/(1 + v)/(1 - 2 v);
R = 1;
con = (1 + 1000 #1) &;
rs = Rationalize[Sqrt[$MachineEpsilon]];

equ = {Pr'[r] + (Pr[r] - Pt[r])/r == 0, u[rs] == rs, Pr[1] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[equ, {u}, {r, rs, 1}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {u[rs] == rs, 
       u'[rs] == Rationalize[13.3709]}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
{Plot[Evaluate[u[r] /. sol], {r, rs, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "u"}], 
 LogLogPlot[Evaluate[u'[r] /. sol], {r, rs, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"r", "u'"}]}
```

[image: fig1]
Calculate

```
Pr[1] /. sol

Out[]= {-4.9329723767604719*10^-14}
```

At first glance, the solution is obtained with high accuracy, but if we calculate

```
Pr[1]*Ev /. sol

Out[]= {-0.00157855116056335102}
```

then we will see that zero is still very far. Raise  `WorkingPrecision -> 50`, then we calculate

```
Pr[1]*Ev /. sol

Out[]= {-5.370961405513687831138142980*10^-13}
```

This is close to zero and can be considered a solution to the problem.

Comment: With the increased `WorkingPrecision` you can return to the OP's BC `rs = Rationalize[$MachineEpsilon, 0]`.  Basically I expect that `rs` can be set to be about $10^{-wp/2}$. (I think the desired BC is that $u \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow 0$.)

Comment: The explanation is very clear and thoughful. l learn a lot from you and I’m vrey grateful. Finally, really thank you very much and hope this not didn't spend your time too much @Alex Trounev